# Does any dialect merge "cold" and "culled"?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm a native American English speaker who pronounces `cold/culled`, `colt/cult`, and `told/toad` the same way (first word in each pair with weak L compared to Merriam-Webster). It only recently became clear to me that these sounds are distinct, and I have a lot of trouble pronouncing the second word of each pair.

Some mergers like cot/caught are well-known, but I'm wondering if my problem is just individual. In hindsight I've been asked to repeat myself when saying words like "pulse" or "bulb". I grew up in NYC and am a heritage Chinese speaker.

Comment: Not aware of any but you could have a look at [this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects).

Comment: The deletion of /l/ in *told* is common in British English, but the resultant isn't necessarily the same as *toad.* Similarly for *cold,* but not *colt.*

Comment: Generally mergers like this are distributed socioeconomically, and not geographically. It depends on the groups you identify with, not where you live. In olden days, when nobody moved very far from their birthplace, there was no difference; but now we've got very distinct social groupings in modern cities, and they talk different.

Comment: Those examples seem to all fall under the difficulty encountered by Chinese speakers with English pronunciation. If you spoke Chinese at home as a child, this could explain it. This tool will reproduced the sounds, it's really great: https://tophonetics.com/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Wikipedia calls it the [hull-hole merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/l/#Hull%E2%80%93hole_merger) and says that some North American speakers have it. Unfortunately, it doesn't narrow it down to any specific regions.

[This web page](https://www.acelinguist.com/2019/05/the-colt-cult-merger.html) gives anecdotal evidence that it happens in Pennsylvania.

Comment: Generally mergers like this are distributed socioeconomically, and not geographically. It depends on the groups you identify with, not where you live.

Comment: @JohnLawler What exactly do you mean by "like this"? Which mergers are and aren't distributed that way, and how can we distinguish?

Comment: They're all distributed that way; that's the norm. Of course sociolinguistic surveys were not available in the past, but as soon as we learned how to do them, that's the first thing we found out for sure. As for which mergers, for instance, there's all the mergers and splits involved in the current Northern Cities Vowel Shift -- which is getting lots of surveys, or the Great Vowel Shift some centuries earlier, which had none.

Comment: @JohnLawler: There are lots of mergers that are distributed regionally ***and*** socio-economically. Speaker without the *cot-caught* merger are rare on the West Coast, no matter what socio-economic class they bellong to, and the *pin-pen* merger is much more common in the South than anywhere else in the country. (Of course, people in higher socio-economic classes tend to move around more, so high-class regional accents are some combination of General American and the lower-class regional accent of that region, unlike the days of JFK where there ***was*** a distinct high-class Boston accent.)

Comment: Often, when groups are segregated, regions are valid proxies for social groups. And of course, the longer folks have been talking English in a place, the more likely it is to have a local lect that's folded in. Like the situation in England. But they haven't been doing it here or in Oz very long.